# Gradle (android experimental plugin) ignores a project dependency

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental

I'm using Gradle Android Experimental plugin in the following project structure:

```
Root Project
|-- app
|-- my-library
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':my-library', ':app'
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "a.bundle.id"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile project(':my-library')
}
```

**my-library/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 'android-23'
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.1'

        defaultConfig.with {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "xxx"
        CFlags += "-I" + "${project.buildDir}".toString() + "/../src/main/jni/libabecs/include"
        CFlags += "-std=gnu99"
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDir 'src/main/jni/libxxx/src'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
        }

        create("all")
    }
}
```

The library project builds perfectly fine. In Android Studio, it doesn't show any error. However, when attempting to build this project with Gradle, it'll only attempt to build the `app` project and will practically ignore the `my-library` dependency, rendering class not found errors.

How to solve this?

Comment: it looks like a plugin issue, have you filed a bug report?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it's a bug/feature not implemented in the build plugin.

I only found a dirty workaround to link the generated aar directly.

build.gradle (someappname)

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs '../my-library/build/outputs/aar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':my-library')
    compile(name:'my-library-{flavour}', ext:'aar')
    //the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem, and finally found out that the path to the ndk sources in my library project was wrong, and that I had to add:

```
dependencies {
    project ":myHybridLib"
}
```

in the `android.sources.main.jni` of the main project.

After correcting those errors, everything compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0):

change `my_library/build.gradle` to something like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

model {

android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig.with {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }
}

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "FlatBuffersParser"
    cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11', '-fexceptions', '-Wall', '-Wno-literal-suffix'])
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/flatbufferslib")}".toString())
    ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
    stl = "gnustl_shared"
   }
}
```

for more info about structure see this project in github, it uses experimental v0.4.0 in two android module :

https://github.com/frogermcs/FlatBuffs

Answer (score -3):

Faced the same issue. I workaround it by renaming app submodule to something else. So the project structure will be

```
Root Project
|-- someappname
|-- my-library
```

**settings.gradle**:

```
include ':my-library', ':someappname'
```